# The suitable brush for toes in sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting, brushes

I'm trying to make a character in blender and stuck with feet in sculpting mode. I can't find suitable brush to create toes. I've tried to "grab" it, but it breaks my topology, tried to "snake hook" it, but the only thing i'm getting is a sharp hooks. For now, the best thing for me is a "blob", but maybe there is something more suitable, because it still looks ugly.
[image: Toes with "blob" brush]

Comment: Do you want separated toes or just carvings?

Comment: @Blunder can you explain the difference between separated and carvings? I can't understand what you mean. I planning to rig it to get compatibility with ue4 skeleton.

Comment: I mean something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzFgG.jpg) where the gaps are etched in but the toes are actually still joined together. I think sculpting separated individual toes is hard because they are very close together. And do you need these details when you want to rig and animate the feet anyway? It might be easier just to sculpt a rough base shape, do the retopology, and then bake the details into a normal map from a MultiRes modifier that is on the low-poly version.

Comment: @Blunder I already experienced how hard it is, but I think I should do it in this way to improve my skills faster. Even if i won't need it for rig and animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Blob* is probably a good brush, don't forget to enable the *Dyntopo* option in order to create additional faces:

[image]

Also you can use the *Inflate* brush afterwards:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it looks like I can work with it.